# How to monitor file upload progress?

Tags: java, post, upload

I need to upload a file to server and monitor it's progress.
i need to get a notification how many bytes are sent each time.

For example in case of download i have:

```
HttpURLConnection  connection = (HttpURLConnection) m_url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
while ((currentBytes  = stream.read(byteBuffer)) > 0) {                    
    totalBytes+=currentBytes;
    //calculate something...
}
```

Now i need to do the same for upload. but if use

```
OutputStreamWriter stream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
stream.write(str);
stream.flush();
```

than i can't get any progres notification, about how many bytes are sent (it looks like automic action).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It's a shame you didn't get a real answer to this question, I was curious...

Comment: it seems that HttpURLConnection  is not the right object for the task. it is non blocking for output, so i can't measure performance with it. i'm trying to use sockets now.

Comment: Yeah, with sockets you can use getSendBufferSize to determine when they are sending data.

Comment: It isn't 'non-blocking for output'. @MirroredFate getSendBufferSize() doesn't 'determine when they are sending data'. It returns a value that is fixed unless you change it yourself. It doesn't vary with send progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used ChannelSocket object. This object allows to do blocking read and write when accessing the server. So i emulated HTTP using this socket and each write request was blocked untill it was done. This way i could follow the actual progress of write transaction.

Answer (score 5):

Just set chunked transfer mode and monitor your own writes to the output stream.

If you don't use chunked or fixed-length transfer mode, your writes are all written to a ByteArrayOutputStream before being written to the network, so that Java can set the Content-Length header correctly. This is what made you think it is non-blocking. It isn't.

Comment: Indeed `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(2048);` did the trick.

Comment: @btoueg 'It is for streaming so it won't work as expected' why?

Comment: It depends what your need is. If you need to upload 2Mb~5Mb documents, there is no point streaming them.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Certainly there is a point to it. It saves you 2-5MB of memory by not writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream. You still haven't stated *why* it 'won't work as expected', and you now haven't stated what is so special about the 2-5MB range, or why it only applies to documents.

Comment: What the OP wants is monitoring file upload progress. Your answer suggests to use the chunked transfer mode. Unfortunately, this mode is only available for streaming content. If your server does not support streaming, you will get an error. On the other hand, you could subclass an outputstream just like @Phill suggested, which would enable you to monitor upload progress. I can't think of a use case where you would need to spare 2-5MB of memory, unless there is a performance issue, and early optimization is the root of all evil. BTW, I never said it only applies to documents.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg You're missing the point. If you don't use chunked or fixed-length transfer mode, all you can monitor is the transfer into the `ByteArrayOutputStream,` which is of no actual interest. If you want to monitor transfer *over the network,* you have to use a mode where the output stream actually is the network, not a buffer.

Comment: Indeed, the point it to have your OutputStream being consumed by your network process.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg And those modes are chunked or fixed-length transfer mode. That's what this answer says,

Answer (score 2):

What I have done in similar situations is create a subclass of [FilterOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) which overrides the write(...) methods and can then notify your code of any written bytes.

Comment: Hi. I saw such example, but maybe i didn't understand it. I mean when i write to the stream (using write method single time) i do know how many bytes i have written, but i don't see the progress on it. They might be sent to the server only upon flush method.

Comment: @Sophie I had a similar issue as well. The bytes are cached and only written after a certain time. You can solve this problem by setting the content length in advance if you know it - see HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode for more info.

Comment: ok thank, but still if i call write() 1 time with a large text file, I will not see a notification on each chunk that is being sent, right?

Comment: If you need a notification on each byte, do something like the answer MirroredFate gave. Write the bytes one at at a time (or a small amount at a time).

Comment: no, no. the ideal is to get notification on each chunk being sent to server by the API, without interfereing the way the file is being split to packets over the network.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the bytes you're uploading, write the objects as byte arrays to the output stream itself, like you are doing with the input stream.

Comment: yeah, but that would be intervene with the way the file would be chunked if i didn't slipt it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It would be similar to the way your download works.

```
OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
for(byte b: str.getBytes()) {                    
    totalBytes+=1;
    stream.write(b);
    if(totalBytes%50 == 0)
        stream.flush(); //bytes will be sent in chunks of 50
    //calculate something...
}
stream.flush();
```

Something like that.

Comment: calling write doesn't necessarily send these bytes to the server adn i need to messure the response time.

Comment: Depending on the output stream, you are write.  However... I can modify this a bit...

Comment: it can work, but still i would like to get notifications when each packet is sent , without configuring explicitly the size being sent.

Comment: Ahhh... You might want to edit your question to say that.  Add something like, "My question is how can I get a notification every time this sends a packet?"

Comment: this is not working after all because thewrite method is non blocking method, so it returns regardless when the actual write is performed.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is polling the server asking how much of the data is uploaded. Maybe using an id or something.

POST -> /uploadfile

- id
- file

POST -> /queryuploadstate (Returns the partial size)

- id

Of course it needs the servlets to be connected and doesn't allow clustering...