# Http Post using HttpConnection get Progress of the files uploaded

Tags: java

I am uploading the file using HttpConnection in Java
I want to monitor the progress of the uploading to show progress bar

I am unable to find the way to this.

Please help me.. Or tell me links to some tutorials for achieving this

Thanks in Advance

Ramandeep S.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294661/how-to-monitor-file-upload-progress

Comment: I had been in the same situation. What we did was take the "size" of the request and with the quality of the connection measure some "expected time". But of course, that was just a big lie to have something to display. If you achieve this, please post it. Maybe this [link](http://www.17od.com/2010/02/18/multipart-form-upload-on-android/) might be usefull. Here's [another](http://delimitry.blogspot.com.ar/2011/08/android-upload-progress.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use chunked transfer mode, and wrap a javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInoutStream wrapped around the file input stream.